# spyder alternative for f1 matlab help feature

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, shortcut, spyder

In matlab whenever the cursor is on a function, ex: for or plot etc..., and you hit f1, a small window opens with the basic syntax and usage. Is something like that there for python spyder.

ctrl+i is not useful for general commands like for or int.

I searched a lot online... And I am new to Python and am going through a huge piece of code and would appreciate finding a shortcut for the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you can jump to the function definition itself by right-clicking and selecting "Go to definition" from the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder doesn't have built-in documentation for python language.
But python itself have it. All you need to do is to run command *help* in yout IPython/Python console with argument of keyword you're interested of. For example:

```
In [5]: help("for")
The "for" statement
*******************

The "for" statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence
...
```

Other option is to read some guide about language basics, for example [tutorial on python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) .

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Kite https://kite.com/. It's a plugin for Spyder and other editors.
You can put Kite's window next to Spyder's window and it gives you the Documentation relative to what your cursor in Spyder is on. It's a bit like Ctrl+i but works for all commands.
I am also transitioning from Matlab and I find it useful.